# how to use "the same"

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm currently participating in a class to practice English by speaking only in it.
But there is a person who always talks too much for other people to get a chance to speak. Here, I'd like to say like this.( there are 3 people in a group.)

> 1. It has to be guaranteed that we can speak the same amount.
> 2. It has to be guaranteed that I can speak the same amount as the others do

Are these two sentences the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, they seem to mean the same thing to me. Why do you think they could differ in meaning?

Comment: amount for 'speaking' seems awkward, at least to me... surprising is...I'm not getting any other option as well ;P

Comment: @MaulikV How about this? it has to be guaranteed that each of us can speak the same amount as others do.

Comment: I've noticed that your questions are sometimes more on the 'proofreading' side, that is, you are trying to come up with natural-sounding expressions. You might try using the [lang-8](http://lang-8.com/) website for that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

They mean the same thing, but neither is particularly naturally worded.  The passive construction and verb choice make them a bit awkward, I think.  Consider the following alternatives:

> I would like us to all speak the same amount in our group.
>
> We should allot everyone equal time to speak.

or, if you'd like the phrase to be more imperative,

> We must ensure that each member of our group receives equal speaking time.